# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function db2_connect()

Tags: php, db2, laragon

I have some problem. I have been looking it for almost a week. I have done include ibm_db2.dll, change php version but not working. When I run the db2 query, it shows `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function db2_connect() in C:\laragon\www\hpc_dev\db2_conn.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\hpc_dev\index.php(3): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\hpc_dev\db2_conn.php on line 15`

Currently I am using php version 7.4.12 64bit (ts) using laragon in Windows 10. I also have tested using Xampp and the same problem occur. Below are my codes to connect to ibm db2:

db2_conn.php:

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$database = 'DB2';
$user = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$hostname = 'xx.xx.xx';
$port = 60000;

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" .
  "HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo "Connection failed.";
}

?>
```

My code to show data from db2:

```
<?php

include("db2_conn.php");
   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYER WHERE EMPR_LOGIN_NAME = 'xxxxx'";

if ($conn) 
{
 $stmt = db2_exec($conn, $sql);
 $row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt);

 echo $row['SECTOR_DESC'];
 db2_close($conn);
}
?>
```

I don't know either the problem comes from db2 extension or others. Please help me.
For information, I have download the ibm db2 extension here: https://github.com/ibmdb/php_ibm_db2

Thanks

Comment: In addition to downloading the extension, did you enable it in you `php.ini` and restart the webserver?

Comment: @Barmar yes, I have enable and restart the webserver

Comment: Did you install  the prerequisite CLIDRIVER ?

Comment: @mao yes, install

Comment: If you open a command prompt (cmd.exe) and enter the command `db2level`, what is the text output of that command?

Comment: @mao it show `DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11054" with level identifier
"0605010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.4000.1449", "s2006161200",
"DYN2006161200WIN64", and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".`

Comment: I used laragon , with the pre-delivered php version 7.2.19,  and then added the matching TS build for php_ibm_db2, configured php.ini, bounced the services, and the `db2_connect()` works correctly in a script in the terminal window. It helps to verify in the terminal window that you can connect at the command line if you have a db2 client that has that functionality, else can use `db2cli validate -connect ...`

Answer (score 0):

Your question omits details of the command-lines and actions you performed.

Most likely you missed a step in the configuration.

Remember to open the laragon terminal and verify that the Db2 driver is loaded:

`php -m | grep ibm`

should return `ibm_db2` if you have correctly configured the correct version of the extension.

If you do not see that the `ibm_db2` extension is loaded then any `db2_connect` will fail until you resolve the missing module.

For information the current laragon_full (November 2020) delivers PHP 7.2 TS, and that works correctly with the php_ibm_db2.dll TS for v7.2.x "out of the box" (which you must first download and configure).

Additionally, if I upgrade the PHP version for laragon to PHP 7.4.12 TS, and subsequently download and configure the matching php_ibm_db2.dll TS for php v7.4.x, then it all "just works" without any issues on Win 10 x64 2020 to connect to Db2-LUW and run queries etc.

It helps to verify that your Db2 client is correctly configured. You can do that independently of PHP. If you are using the `clidriver`  Db2-client (the smallest footprint driver) you can configure the `db2dsdriver.cfg` XML file and then run `db2cli validate -connect -dsn -user ... -passwd ...` to verify that the connection works. If you are using either the Db2-runtime-client or the Db2 full client, or a local Db2-server, you can run (in the laragon terminal):

(after configuring your Db2 node directory and Db2 db directory via appropriate configuration commands )::

```
set DB2CLP=**$$**

db2 connect to $yourdsn user ... using ...
```